# Is it possible to get the random number previously generated by std::uniform_int_distribution?

Tags: c++11, random

If I generate random numbers with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 999);

    for (int n=0; n<1000; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

is it possible to get the previously generated values in the reverse order (without saving them into an array, etc...) after the loop is finished, and do something like this:

```
    for (int n=0; n<1000; ++n)
        std::cout << GetPrev(dis, gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
```

?

Comment: No it's not possible. You have to save the numbers yourself. If you want them in reverse order might I suggest a [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?

Answer (score 0):

If you seed the pseudo random engine with the same value, it will generate the same sequence of bits, which will translate in the distribution generating the same numbers. So you need to store the seed passed to the constructor of mt19937.